# How to find intersection of two number fields in SageMath

Tags: sage

I would like to find the intersection of two number fields in Sagemath, but I'm not sure exactly how to set this up.

In some cases, I am able to find the intersection using the `subfields()` method: for example, if I know the intersection is multiquadratic, I can compute the discriminants of all the quadratic subfields of my two number fields, and then find the intersection by adjoining all the common discriminants to `RationalField()`. This method doesn't generalize very well, particularly if I don't know the degree of the intersection, so I'm wondering: is there a better way?

Answer (score -2):

```
# Define the two number fields
K = NumberField(x^2 - 2, 'alpha')
L = NumberField(x^2 - 3, 'beta')

# Find the intersection of the two number fields
intersection = K.composite_field(L)

# Print the intersection
print(intersection)
```

Define two number fields K and L using the NumberField constructor. The first argument to the constructor is the defining polynomial of the number field, and the second argument is an optional name for the generator of the field.

Then, use intersection() method of the K number field object and pass L as the argument. This computes the intersection of the two number fields.

Finally, print the intersection object, which represents the intersection of the two number fields.

The intersection object will be another number field, which you can manipulate further or perform computations on as needed.

Note that the intersection() returns the smallest number field that contains both K and L. If the intersection is a subfield of K or L, then the returned field will be isomorphic to the intersection.

Using the intersection() is generally more efficient and reliable compared to manually computing subfields, especially when you don't know the degree of the intersection in advance.

Comment: When I copy-paste your code in my console, I get the following error: `'NumberField_quadratic_with_category' object has no attribute 'intersection'`. Any idea what's going on there? I am running Sage 10.0.beta6

Comment: wow, my answer was downvoted, I edited it for the beta version you have.....

Comment: Not sure why you were downvoted - I've upvoted because this is very useful, even if my particular sage environment is messing things up. I got the same error with the `composite_field` method... maybe this is a good lesson about the dangers of using beta versions

Comment: Your answer got downvoted because yo used AI. [You must stop using chatgpt](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned)

Comment: It is `composite_fields` but not `composite_field`, but it is not the up expect

Comment: Just an update: `composite_fields` returns (as one might expect), the composite of the two number fields, not the intersection. I am still looking for a function that returns the intersection